# Get the nth field of a structure

Tags: matlab, struct

I need to have access to the n element of a structure in Matlab.

Let say, I have a structure define by

```
struc.a = 1;
struc.b = 3;
struc.c = 2;
```

I would like to be able to access the second element of the structure and get the number 3 as answer.

Comment: What do you mean by second? To have something second you need to define an order of the fields, like sort them by name? So in your case 'b' would be second? what if you have different field names, that sort differently?

Comment: @Marcin Matlab has a define order for the element in a structure which is link with the order you define your structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found a slightly more elegant method than @Dan using the [dynamic field names](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2008/08/20/advanced-matlab-dynamic-field-names/).

```
n = 2;
fields = fieldnames(struc);
struc.(fields{n})
```

Comment: This is much better - you should accept this over mine

Comment: @Dan There is a minimum amount of time before I can accept my own answer ;)

Answer (score 8):

```
n = 2;
fields = fieldnames(struc);
getfield(struc, fields{n})
```